# Как заменить цикл for?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
print(True if False in [all(list(map(int, input().split()))) for i in range(10)] else False)
```

все выводит правильно, но когда в тесте 2 строчки , то в цикле то остается 10 и выдает поэтому ошибку

**Ввод**

```
1 3 4
4 5 7
```

**Ожидаемый результат**

```
False
```

**Вывод**

```
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'run' failed
```

если же в цикле поставить вместо 10 - 2 , то будет все прекрасно работать

как можно сделать так, чтобы под каждый случай изменялось число в цикле `for` ?

Comment: В числе 70 есть ноль.

Comment: А надо искать числа 0 или цифры 0? Ну т.е. 70 - это есть ноль или только отдельный 0 это 0?

Comment: @CrazyElf отдельный 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

а там нет ошибки в задаче - ну что или из файла надо вычитать или сначала ввести кол-во строк?

многострочный вариант возможен без этого:

```
lines = ""

while True:
    line = input()
    if not line:
        break
    lines += line + " "

print(any(map(lambda i: int(i) == 0, lines.split())))
```

или так:

```
print(not all(map(bool, map(int, lines.split()))))
```

в общем скорее всего данные передаются или через stdin или через файл, в первом случае тогда

```
import sys
print(not all(map(bool, map(int, sys.stdin.read().split()))))
```

или вообще можно сделать так:

```
print(" 0 " in f" {sys.stdin.read()} "))
```

дешево и сердито :)

**P.S.**

кстати описанный выше подход можно и через `split` легко сделать :)

```
print("0" in text.split())
```

чтоб уж совсем коротенько